# How to get root path of the app container with reading from userDomainMask for comparison checks?

Tags: swift

I an reading the contents of directory in the library directory like this:

```
FileManager.default.urls(for: .libraryDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first?
    .appendingPathComponent("Sounds")
```

In different scenario's I get the following absolute paths when I get a file:

```
file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/DE78-43C6-BB73-4DA0E2B9D799/Library/Sounds/abc123.m4a
```

And other times I get a `private` directory in the path:

```
file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/DE78-43C6-BB73-4DA0E2B9D799/Library/Sounds/abc123.m4a
```

How can I normalize this because I want to compare if one of the files exist in an another array, but because of all the scenarios with and without `private`, my comparison checks fails?

Comment: You should not, actually that's why file system is not available directly. Probably the only you can use is `Sounds/file_name.m4a`.

Comment: I think I found what I need which is the `standardizedFileURL` property on the URL which removes `private`. The docs isn't clear what exactly this does or why it removes `private`.